# How to construct a closed, filled, path made of semi-circles and attach annotations to it with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have very limited LaTeX knowledge. I am trying to plot the following figure using "tikz" and I appreciate if anyone can help me to finish plotting my figure. I did the following so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:6);
\draw   (-12,0)  - -(0,0);
\draw (-8,0) arc (0:180:2);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:4);
\draw (-6,-0.1) - - (-6,0.1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is a BIG semi-circle and two inner SMALL semi-circles. I want to label the right endpoint of the BIG semi-circle by "A" and  the left endpoint of the BIG semi-circle by "B". I want to label the center of the BIG semi-circle by "O", and I want to label the point where the two SMALL semicircles meet by "P". I also want to shade the area inside the BIG semi-circle and outside the two SMALL semi-circles. I also want to mention on the figure that the radius of the big circle is: 6. and the distance between the point "O" and the point "P" is "x"

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: @Pleasedonttouch that's a bit too much meaning change for the title. Can you narrow down its focus? They are just semicircles

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch Yes but it's not your question title. Better consult the OP

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch Or you are testing his/her patience.

Comment: @percusse: I am testing your patience. :-)

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch That would take a while then.

Comment: @percusse: Hehehe :-)

Answer (score 16):

You can also draw that path at one go so you don't need to fill white to restrict the fill if you have something else underneath it. And while you are at it you can also place the labels and coordinates too.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=blue] (0,0) 
               coordinate[label=-90:$B$] (B)
               arc (180:0:3cm) 
               coordinate[label=-90:$A$] (A)
               arc (0:180:2cm)
               coordinate[label=-90:$P$] (P)
               arc (0:180:1cm);
\draw (B)--(A) coordinate[midway,label=-90:$O$] (O);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5mm},decorate] (A) -- (O) 
                   node [midway,yshift=-6mm,below] (R) {$6$};
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5mm},decorate] (O) -- (P)
                   node [midway,yshift=-6mm,below] (r) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pathreplacing` instead of `pathmorphing` in line 2 of your code? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AboAmmar Actually, it shouldn't even be there because it loads `brace` by default but you are right. I forgot to remove it from another example code.

Comment: I think no, it should be still there to draw the braces. There must be `decorations.pathreplacing`.

Comment: @AboAmmar Try removing it. `snake`, `brace` and one other thing I don't remember is loaded by default.

Comment: @percusse- It doesn't work if I remove it. Does it work with you?

Comment: @AboAmmar Hmm, you are right again. I'll add the line. Don't know how I even managed to compile when I wrote the answer. More coffee needed probably.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=blue] (0,0)node[below]{$A$} arc (0:180:6) node[below]{$B$};
  \draw (-12,0) - -(0,0);
  \draw[fill=white] (-8,0) arc (0:180:2);
  \draw[fill=white] (0,0) arc (0:180:4)node[below]{$P$};
  \draw (-6,-0.1) -- node[below]{$O$} (-6,0.1);
  \draw[<->](-8,-0.6)--node[below]{$x$}(-6,-0.6);
  \draw[<->](-6,-0.6)--node[below]{$6$}(0,-0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Note that colouring/filling is cumulative: you can fill one region with a colour and then fill another overlapping region with a different colour, or `white` to remove the colour. The last colour in any given region wins.

Answer (score 5):

No `arc`s but with `circle`s and `clip`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-3.1,-0.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle (3,3.1);
\filldraw[fill=blue] (0,0)  circle (3cm);
\filldraw[fill=white] (1,0) circle (2cm);
\filldraw[fill=white] (-2,0) circle (1cm);
\end{scope}
\draw (-3,-0.5\pgflinewidth)
        coordinate[label=-90:$B$] (B)
        -- (-1,-0.5\pgflinewidth) coordinate[label=-90:$P$] (P)
        --coordinate[pos=0.25,label=-90:$O$] (O)
        (3,-0.5\pgflinewidth)coordinate[label=-90:$A$] (A) ;
\draw[|<->|,yshift=-5mm] ([yshift=-5mm]A) -- ([yshift=-5mm]O)
                   node [midway,below] (R) {$6$};
\draw[|<->|] ([yshift=-5mm]O) -- ([yshift=-5mm]P)
                   node [midway,below] (r) {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A recommended solution (by me) with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-2)(5,5)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle=-90]
        (0,0){O}
        (5,0){A}
        (-5,0){B}
        (-2,0){P}
    \begingroup
        \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
        \pstMiddleAB{B}{P}{O'}
        \pstMiddleAB{P}{A}{O''}
    \endgroup
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=NavyBlue]
    {
        \pstArcOAB{O}{A}{B}
        \pstArcnOAB{O'}{B}{P}
        \pstArcnOAB{O''}{P}{A}
        \closepath
    }
    \pcline(B)(A)
    \psset{arrows=|*-|*,shortput=nab}
    \pcline[offset=-1](P)(O)_{$x$}
    \pcline[offset=-1.5](O)(A)_{$r$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The additional dots (to make the points clearer) are given free of charge.